# Specific way of adding style with html.erb?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, dynamic

Have updated the css and html as the answers indicate but unfortunately the style information is still not being passed to the td. The class is defined as limits but no style.

---

Having some trouble with something very basic.

HTML

```
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "test.css" %>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="results">
        <% @result.each do |object|%>
        <tr>
            <td class="limit"> <%= object%> </td>
        </tr>

        <%end%>
    </table>

</body>
```

```
CSS
table.results
{
    width: 100%;
    border: .2em ridge #000000;
}
td.limit
{
    width:50%;
    background-color: #fff000;
    border: .2em ridge #0f0f0f;
}
```

In the resulting output. the table which has its class defined outside the ruby loop has all its style attributes included fine.

However the TD inside the ruby for.each loop does not. Is there some specific way to add a class to a HTML element in Ruby?

---

output html table as requested

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Crawler</title>
  <link href="/stylesheets/globalStyleSheet.css?1312383253" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.inputlimiter.1.0.css?1312464674" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/test.css?1313055311" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/controls.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="fQ/oa3q+Aq68GZenV26YuwPjDgbijTeuO3VJihtYHI8="/>
</head>
<body>

<html>
    <head>

         <link href="/stylesheets/test.css?1313055311" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <table class="results">
            <tr id="test-tr">
                <td class="limit"> blag blah </td>
            </tr>

            <tr >
                <td class="limit"> testing 45 </td>

            </tr>

            <tr >
                <td class="limit"> testing</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @fl00r a bit strange. theres 2 extra closing body and html tags at the bottom but I didnt put them there

Comment: As @fl00r says, show your generated HTML. And make sure that the link that's generated to your stylesheet is correct, too -- does the `href` attribute of the generated `link` point to the right place?

Comment: @Matt Gibson. I've already shown the generated html. And it is definitely finding the stylesheet just fine as the table's style is going through and it has a border. the inner td or tr does not.

Comment: Can you get that sylesheet link moved up into the real `<head>` of your document, rather than appearing in a second, illegal `<head>` within your body? That would eliminate that as the cause of some confusion, at least. Also, what do those other stylesheets you're including (e.g. /globalStyleSheet.css?1312383253) do? Is there a chance they're also applying table styles, perhaps with more importance? Given that your provided HTML and CSS [work in isolation](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/bcX4W/1/), something else must be interfering.

Comment: [I pasted your file onto my server, changing only the second link to test.css, and putting just the styles above into my own test.css](http://www.fysh.org/~gothick/so/test.html). The style seems to apply fine to me in Safari and Firefox, i.e. the background is yellow and the cells have a border.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semicolon after the `background-color` property in the CSS for your `td`. That'll be knocking out both the `background-color` and `border` properties.

You may want to take advantage of the [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) for basic sanity checking of your CSS. In your case, it says:

> td.limit  Value Error : background-color attempt to find a semi-colon before the property name. add it

...which is a bit cryptic, I admit, but at least a reasonable pointer towards your problem.

Comment: Ok I've updated the question slightly. Unfortunately the td is still not getting any style information passed to it. the class is there but no style

Comment: I think we need to see your generated table HTML. I've put an example of what I think your generated HTML could look like, along with my correction to your CSS, [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/bcX4W/), and it seems to work fine. The important thing to note here is that the Ruby isn't important in terms of the styling, unless it's generating the wrong HTML -- it's the generated HTML (view your page source) and the CSS that applies to that that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about Ruby or Rails at all.

You have got EXTRA space between `class` and `="limit"`

```
<td class ="limit"> <%= object%> </td>
#=> should be
<td class="limit"><%= object %></td>
```

Comment: "White space is allowed around the equal sign." -- [Understanding HTML and SGML, w3.org](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/HTMLandSGML.html). Though I don't know whether this is true for every single DOCTYPE.